# Unity 2d stutters when running left-right

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine

I'm working on messing with the penny pixel demo.

Seen here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tDX2ChhntD8

Downloadable here:
https://oc.unity3d.com/index.php/s/nS02rplRWJN1d6C

It seems to stutter every so often when I'm running long distances left-right. Here's a video of it:
https://youtu.be/GFtjfI1cje8

The code for the camera is here:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject player;
    public Camera main_camera;

    void Update()
    {
        if (player != null)
        {
            float player_x = player.transform.position.x;
            float player_y = player.transform.position.y;

            float rounded_x = RoundToNearestPixel(player_x);
            float rounded_y = RoundToNearestPixel(player_y);

            Vector3 new_pos = new Vector3(rounded_x, rounded_y, -10.0f); // this is 2d, so my camera is that far from the screen.
            main_camera.transform.position = new_pos;
        }
    }
    public float pixelToUnits = 40f;

    public float RoundToNearestPixel(float unityUnits)
    {
        float valueInPixels = unityUnits * pixelToUnits;
        valueInPixels = Mathf.Round(valueInPixels);
        float roundedUnityUnits = valueInPixels * (1 / pixelToUnits);
        return roundedUnityUnits;
    }
}
```

Comment: Personally, I do think putting a bunch of YouTube links and another link to a download does discourage nearly everyone from helping you.

Comment: I've added the code, but the link is an official Unity tutorial, and then my video.

Comment: You could also read [Jon's article on how to ask the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: @JonathanBurk I haven't watch the videos yet, but a quick piece of advice, since you are updating the camera's position to follow the players transform position, which I can only assume from what you have posted is handling movement in an update/FixedUpdate, move your camera's position code to a LateUpdate.